# switching scenes within the same stage

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, fxml

i have been surfing the web and haven't quite managed to find anything that's working with my current setup/code.

So I may just be doing something wrong but here's what I got so far:

```
Parent dashboardParent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("dashboard.fxml"));
        Scene dashboardScene = new Scene(dashboardParent);
        Stage window = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        window.setScene(dashboardScene);
        window.show();
        System.out.println("Success");
```

I have tried many variants of a similar thing that seems to be working for other people, so I'd appreciate if anyone could help me

It definitely gets that far, as it prints the success message.

In a nutshell, I have my login page and when the user logs in, I want it to change the scene, displaying the dashboard.

EDIT:

Method it is in:

```
private void clickLogin(MouseEvent event) throws SQLException, IOException {     
    String query1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username  = ? OR email = ?) AND password = ?";
    con = handler.getConnection();
    pst = con.prepareStatement(query1);
    pst.setString(1, usernameField.getText());
    pst.setString(2, usernameField.getText());
    pst.setString(3, passwordField.getText());

    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

    if(!rs.isBeforeFirst()){
        System.out.println("Failed.");
    } else {  

        Parent dashboardParent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("dashboard.fxml"));
        Scene dashboardScene = new Scene(dashboardParent);
        Stage window = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        window.setScene(dashboardScene);
        window.show();
        System.out.println("Success");

    }
```

I commented out the following lines:

both using // and /* */.

```
private void clickLogin(MouseEvent event) throws SQLException, IOException {     
    //String query1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username  = ? OR email = ?) AND password = ?";
    //con = handler.getConnection();
    //pst = con.prepareStatement(query1);
    //pst.setString(1, usernameField.getText());
   // pst.setString(2, usernameField.getText());
   // pst.setString(3, passwordField.getText());

   // ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();


        Parent dashboardParent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("dashboard.fxml"));
        Scene dashboardScene = new Scene(dashboardParent);
        Stage window = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        window.setScene(dashboardScene);
        window.show();
    //if(!rs.isBeforeFirst()){
   //     System.out.println("Failed.");
   // } else {  
   //     System.out.println("Success");
   //     
   // }
}
```

and it is still calling the if/else method and displaying the results... how is that possible?

Comment: not quite sure I understand what you mean by the Chicken or Egg problem... and this sits within the controller of the UI so how would I go about getting the stage from the start method?

Comment: What actually happens? There is nothing obviously wrong with the code you posted, so the cause of whatever problem you have is likely to be in other parts of your code. Post a [MCVE].

Comment: Well i just replicated what I was trying to do from scratch and it worked.. so there's nothing wrong with the code. Maybe it's something to do with where i'm doing it? Edited the post, with the whole method inc

Comment: I just tried putting it outside the if else statement and still the same thing. It just doesn't display the other form.

PS Edited main post

Comment: If when you run the program it does not execute the current code in your IDE then it means you need to clean and/or rebuild the project.

Comment: I didn't think that could have been an issue. Turns out that was the issue all along. I guess because it was still running the sql querying and returning my system.out messages, i assumed it was all working fine. Thanks for your help

Comment: user can you post an answer please :)